# Apache2 NTLM Authentication on specific URL

Tags: apache-2.2, directory, single-sign-on, ntlm

I have a problem.
I'm using Legrandin's NTLM Authentication Module [PyAuthenNTLM2](https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2) with my Apache2 server. 
It really works well and it was easy to install. I recommend it to everybody.

The authentication works perfectly fine. But I have a problem once POST-Requests are sent.
Everytime a POST is sent to the server, IE's annoying credentials prompt keeps appearing.
Even though I checked "Remember my Credentials". This is how I have it configured right now:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            AuthType NTLM
            AuthName DOMAIN
            require valid-user

            PythonAuthenHandler pyntlm
            PythonOption Domain DOMAIN
            PythonOption PDC 123.45.67.89
            PythonOption BDC 123.45.67.89

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

My question to you guys:

Is it possible to do the authentication only on one single URL?

For example: If a user access my page for the first time, the URL will be: http://domain.com/custom/login. This URL doesn't represent the directory though. It's just a controller of the Zend Framework.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do is use the `<Location>` container, which maps URLs to options, like:

```
<Location /custom/login>
    ... options ...
</Location>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I tried replacing the Directory Tag with a Location tag (like in your example) and it didn't work.

Comment: It did not work at all, or produced the same results as before?

Comment: This is what gets logged:

[Fri Mar 16 15:35:08 2012] [notice] [client IP] PYNTLM: User username/DOMAIN has been authenticated to access URI /custom/index/login

Looks like the <Location>-Tag fires. I will check the code now and see if it gets the REMOTE_USER.

Comment: I can verify that I get a value for the property PHP_AUTH_USER with <Location /> but not with <Location /custom/login>.

Comment: I just saw that the username gets passed to another variable, if you use <Location /custom/index/login>. The username is now available in $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']. It works Kyle, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Interesting.  Glad it worked for you.